# Can Apex data loader be installed in Windows server 2012

Tags: data-loader

Will data loader work in windows server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ducumentation says

System Requirements To use Data Loader, you need:

- Microsoft® Windows® 7 or Windows XP
- 120 MB free disk space
- 256 MB available memory
- Java JRE 1.6 or later (Windows 7 or Windows XP)
- Sun JVM 1.6 or later (Windows 7 or Windows XP)
- Administrator privileges on the machine

However in my experience if you match the JRE requirements, it also works on Windows 8 and Server 2012.

Comment: Hello Uwe, was you able to run Data Loader's command line on those Server OS (2008,2012)? Please let me know.

Comment: Is compatible with windows server 2016 too ?